# Clustering, classification and regression pipeline for forecasting the power generation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, cluster-analysis, random-forest

I am trying to forecast the power generation by PV cells using Machine learning. I used Random forest and SVM RBF regression models and the results are quite accurate. However, it was observed that the prediction model performs best for sunny weather and not so good for cloudy/rainy weather.

I decided to break this problem into subproblems and built a clustering, classification and regression pipeline. First I am doing k-means clustering to label the days and after that, a classifier is trained using the cluster labels as a target variable. Then I am applying different regression model for each cluster.

I am relatively new to the field of Machine learning and would like to know if this approach makes sense? Also, am I introducing redundancy? It would be great if someone can tell me pros/cons of this approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted at CV (where it makes *marginally* more sense): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/322582/1352

Answer (score 2):

There exists piecewise regression.

Yes, it can make sense sometimes. You'll probably want your predictions to be smooth and continuous, though.